# How to resolve this SQL Server 2016 master data services authentication error on the web application?

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

I just installed MS SQL server, IIS and Master Data services, 2016 version. Everything seems fine, except the web application doesn't work. I am able to go to the home screen, but there are no models/versions listed in the Model: and Version: dropdown, even though I added two models using the MDSModelDeploy utility. The UI doesn't give me any error, but Chrome dev tools shows "401 Unauthorised" error.

So basically, the url "http://server-name:port/api/Models" is unreachable, giving "authorization has been denied for this request" error.

I've checked the usual places (allowing anonymous auth etc), they all seem correct. What else should I try?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358903/troubleshooting-master-data-services-mds-permission-authorization) answer.

Comment: Suggest you put your solution as an answer so others can be benefited in future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sqlworldwide for pointing me to this question, which worked

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358903/troubleshooting-master-data-services-mds-permission-authorization